# Use react-navigation drawer for narrow screens, side menu for wide screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I would like my react-native app to use a drawer for narrow screens, but have a sticky side menu on wide screens.   I'm using react-navigation, and I can make the menu stick by using this:

```
const AppStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Edit: EditStack
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <EditDrawer {...props} />,
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-open',
    drawerType: 'slide'
  }
);
```

However, this shows the edit area as un-editable, slid to the right with the drawer open.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach this, not necessarily code fixes (though examples are welcome!).   Is it even possible with react-navigation?